# Как определить центр экрана в приложении с прокруткой?

Tags: ios, swift

Простая задача - есть экран с `UITableView`, в которой много ячеек, так много, что они не умещаются на экране. Если я прокручу сильно вниз и размещу `UIView` по центру экрана с помощью `self.view.center`, то эта точка не будет являться реальным центром экрана, в который смотрит пользователь.

Как получить центр именно *экрана*, а не приложения или корневого `view`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы получить центр видимой части, до которой прокручено, возьмите центр и добавьте offset:

```
let screenCenter = CGPointMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width/2, (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height/2 + yourTableView.contentOffset.y))
```

**Swift 3:**

```
let screenCenter = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: (UIScreen.main.bounds.midY + yourTableView.contentOffset.y))
```

Answer (score 0):

Если тебе нужно узнать центр отображаемых данных, то возьми

```
CGPointMake( table.contentSize.width/2, table.contentSize.height/2);
```

PS: под экраном обычно подразумевают физический экран устройства.